# User defined function in Access DCount criteria field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using DCount in a vba script.  The Source and Criteria are both coming from a table.  The system is working in most cases, but I get an error when the criteria includes a user defined function.

The DCount code is

```
Source = list.Fields("source")
criteria = list.Fields("Criteria")
x = DCount("*", Source, criteria)
```

The criteria that fails is "is_Pregnant=1 or Ddiff(HSDemographicsReport.Admin_Date, Infant_DOB)<=30"

The Ddiff function is

```
Function Ddiff(a, b)
If (IsNull(a) Or IsNull(b) Or a < b) Then
    Ddiff = Null
    Else: Ddiff = a - b
    End If
End Function
```

Depending on the record, the data has Is_Pregnant=1 as either true, false or null, and the Ddiff function evaluates to either a number or null.  The criteria phrase works in a query and returns either a true or a null.

The error is

[image]

As far as I can tell, all the pieces are working right - but I still get an error when I put them all together.  Is the problem that I cannot use a user defined function this way, or that the function returns Nulls?  In either case, how can I correct it?

Comment: What is your exact criterium? The user-defined function can produce a Null, and doing a numeric comparison vs Null can generate errors (however, usually not this one).

Comment: @Erik - I want DCount to include records that meet either half of the criteria, even if the other part of the criteria is null.  If both evaluate to null or false, the record doesn't get counted.  That seems to be how DCount works.

Comment: Problem has been resolved - DCount doesn't like the qualified name in the criteria.  I removed the xxxx. part and it works now.